# Pass related object's field in Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model class that extends the `django.contrib.auth.models.User`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, models.CASCADE, unique=True)
  bio = models.TextField()
  date_of_birth = models.DateField()
```

and out of this model I'm making a ModelForm:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['bio', 'date_of_birth']
```

How can I tell the MyModelForm to take in the User's fields such as `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`?

Example in the class Meta fields I can add `['bio', 'date_of_birth', 'user']` but that will just provide me with the dropdown to select to whom shall the MyModel in the MyModelForm be related to.

Doing `['bio', 'date_of_birth', 'user.first_name']` throws an exception `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (user.first_name) specified for MyModel`

Edit: here's the traceback
https://pastebin.com/0T42VKEP

Comment: hey, you can add related field like `user__username` and so on, by appending with double underscore and related model field name.

Comment: Still throwing a FieldError, unknown field exception

Comment: could you please post the error ? or traceback?

Comment: edited it with the traceback

Comment: added a code sample as an answer I use, this skipped my mind that Django doesn't provide any default way to do in forms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I kinda found my own solution, by overriding ModelForm's `__init__` method:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

  first_name = forms.CharField()

  class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['bio', 'date_of_birth']

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    my_user = kwargs.get('instance')
    first_name = my_user.user.first_name
    self.fields['first_name'].initial = first_name #this will show the first name in the html page when i request the instance
```

And when I'm instantiating my form I just pass an instance of MyModel as a 
kwarg: `form = MyModelForm(instance=my_model_instance)`

Comment: i am glad you find a way out for your problem :)

Comment: after `super().__init__`, `self.instance` is set, so you can just use `my_user = self.instance` which is a bit easier to read than getting from the `kwargs`.

Comment: @dirkgroten oh, thanks a lot :) i'm pretty new to django/python so a lot of the subtleties are escaping me

Answer (score 1):

You can use [InlinFormset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). Here I am posting a code sample used by me that might help you. I have modified a bit according to your need, so if anything doesn't work let me know.

```
#forms.py
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = MyModel
```

then in your views you should do like

```
def profileEdit(request,username):
    # querying the User object with pk from url
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)

    # prepopulate MyModelForm with retrieved user values from above.
    user_form = UserForm(instance=user)

    MyModelInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(User, MyModel,can_delete=False, fields="__all__")
    formset = MyModelInlineFormset(instance=user)

    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.id == user.id:
        if request.method == "POST":
            user_form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
            formset = MyModelInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)

            if user_form.is_valid():
                created_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                formset = MyModelInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=created_user)

                if formset.is_valid():
                    created_user.save()
                    formset.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        return render(request, "profile_edit.html", {
            'title':'Edit -'+ user.get_full_name(),
            "user_form": user_form,
            "formset": formset,
        })
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

and in your profile_edit.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% if messages %}
    <div>
    {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">  <!-- singular -->
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
                {{ message|safe }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
        <h2 class="flow-text">Update your information</h2>
          <form action="." method="POST" class="padding" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in user_form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.errors }}
       <label for="{{ field.label }}" >{{ field.label }}</label>
        {{ field }}
     {% if field.help_text %}
      <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</small>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}

    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}

        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ field.errors }}
       <label for="{{ field.label }}" >{{ field.label }}</label>
       {{ field }}
      {% if field.help_text %}
      <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</small>
      {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"></input>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```