# User registration using extra fields by extending AbstractUser

Tags: python, django

I asked something similar before, but people don't seem to understand what I ask or maybe I just don't understand, but I'm really trying to find a solution here. So I have a student model which extends AbstractUser like:

```css
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')


class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('phone', 'student_ID', 'photo')
```

```html
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    student_ID = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=14,
                                  validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{14}$',
                                                             message='The ID needs to be 14 characters long.')])
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='students_images')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_student(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Student.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_student(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

And the expected output is this:

[image]

I just don't know how the view is supposed to look like. I figured something in the past, but nothing would have been saved. I want that student will not be able to register unless he fills up all those fields: username, email, phone, student_ID etc. But also, I want that the fields of Student to be editable in database after the user is created by the form submission. I'm new to this, but I really need to get this done.

Comment: You can use [InlinFormset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) for combining fields from two models.
I have just posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427821/pass-related-objects-field-in-django-modelform/48428783#48428783) that is similar to your problem. Have a look an let me know it this help.

Comment: TypeError at /student/signup/
Exception Value: studentsignup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Comment: By using your code I got this error

Comment: yes because in my code i was passing username via url, you may want to exclude that for signup process. my code sample was to edit user profile and not for signup. I hope you understand.

Comment: Hm... Negative.

Comment: could you please post your code ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Q1UkHJQa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163832/discussion-between-sumeet-kumar-and-dann-m).